# Octave lsqlin error in __qp__ occasionally

Tags: octave, nonlinear-optimization

I am using [lsqlin from the octave-forge package optim 1.5.2](https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/function/lsqlin.html) in GNU Octave, version 4.2.1

```
pkg load optim
new_matrix = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
              1, 1, 1, 1, 0;
              1, 1, 0, 0, 1;
              1, 0, 1, 0, 0];

zero_con = zeros (5, 1);
one_con = ones (5, 1);


new_belief = [1; .7; .7; .01];

# but fails with
# new_belief[4] = 0.02;

x = lsqlin (new_matrix, new_belief,
            [], [], [], [],
            zero_con, one_con);
```

As soon as I change new_belief (see comment in code) I get an error:

```
error: __qp__: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 3x3, op2 is 5x1)
error: called from
    quadprog at line 351 column 32
```

Comment: Can you please make a [complete example which can be run](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly without needing to generate some inputs from your text?  You'll increase the chance enormously if someone who might help you can copy and paste some code. For your problem: try to `debug_on_error(1)` then rerun your code. The debugger will stop at the line and you can inspect the vars

Comment: Edited to include the examples. Thank you for that hint. Regarding debug_on_error(1). It stops in quad_prog.m on this line '[x, qp_lambda, exitflag, iter] = __  qp  __ (x0, H, f, Aeq, beq, Ain, bin, maxit);' In both cases all inputs are nearly identical. Only f differs. In both cases it's the same size, but in the case where it works it has the following values 'f=[-2.41; -2.4; -1.71; -1.7; -1.7]' and in the case where it fails it has 'f=[-2.42; -2.4; -1.72; -1.7; -1.7]' @Andy (the __ qp __ call doesn't actually have spaces, but i don't know how to make the comment not interpret that as bold)

Comment: which version of the octave-forge optim package are you using? (pkg list). I get an error "quadprog: equality constraint matrix has incorrect column dimension"

Comment: optim *|   1.5.2      @Andy